Help with Proof of Perron-Frobenius theorem in "Mathematics and Physics of Many Body systems"
In the book Mathematics and Physics of Many Body systems by Hal Tasaki, he gives a proof of a version of the Perron-Frobenius theorem (see below). However I don't follow the line in (2)

Since $u_i m_{i, j} u_j \leq 0$ for any $i \neq j$, we conclude that $v_i m_{i, j} v_j=u_i m_{i, j} u_j$ for any $i \neq j$.

I assume he is probably using positivity of $\sum_{i \neq j} (v_i m_{i, j} v_j-u_i m_{i, j} u_j)$ but can't see why $\sum_{i \neq j} v_i m_{i, j} v_j$ would be positive. Could someone explain why this line follows?
Theorem A. 18 (Perron-Frobenius theorem for a real symmetric matrix) Let $\mathrm{M}=\left(m_{i, j}\right)_{i, j=1, \ldots, N}$ be an $N \times N$ real symmetric matrix (i.e., $m_{i, j}=m_{j, i} \in \mathbb{R}$ ) with the properties that (i) $m_{i, j} \leq 0$ for any $i \neq j$, and (ii) All $i \neq j$ are connected via nonvanishing matrix elements of $\mathrm{M}$, or, more precisely, for any $i \neq j$, we can take a sequence $\left(i_1, \ldots, i_K\right)$ such that $i_1=i, i_K=j$, and $m_{i_k, i_{k+1}} \neq 0$ for all $k=1,2, \ldots, K-1$. Then the lowest eigenvalue of $\mathrm{M}$ is nondegenerate and the corresponding eigenvector $v=\left(v_i\right)_{i=1, \ldots, N}$ can be taken to satisfy $v_i>0$ for all $i$.
Proof Let us present a standard elementary proof based on a variational argument. The essence of the argument is that a state without "nodes" has low energy, an idea standard in quantum mechanics. See (A.4.1). In what follows we assume (without loss of generality) that all components of vectors are real.
(1) We first prove that if an eigenvector $\boldsymbol{u}=\left(u_i\right)_{i=1, \ldots, N}$ of $\mathrm{M}$ satisfies $u_i \geq 0$ for all $i$, then it inevitably satisfies $u_i>0$ for all $i$. For $\alpha>0$ let $\tilde{\mathrm{M}}=\alpha \mathrm{I}-\mathrm{M}$, where $\mathrm{I}$ denotes the identity matrix. By taking $\alpha$ large enough, we can assume that all the eigenvalues of $\tilde{\mathrm{M}}$ are positive, and $(\tilde{\mathrm{M}})_{i, i}>0$ for any $i$. We also have $(\tilde{\mathrm{M}})_{i, j} \geq 0$ for any $i, j$ from (i). By also using (ii) above, we see that there is $n$ such that $\left(\tilde{\mathrm{M}}^n\right)_{i, j}>0$ for any $i, j$. Note that $\boldsymbol{u}$ is an eigenvector of $\tilde{\mathrm{M}}^n$ with a positive eigenvalue, say, $\beta$. Then we have $\beta u_i=\sum_j\left(\tilde{\mathrm{M}}^n\right)_{i, j} u_j$, which implies $u_i>0$ under the assumption that $u_j \geq 0$ and $\boldsymbol{u} \neq 0$.
(2) Let $\boldsymbol{v}=\left(v_i\right)_{i=1, \ldots, N}$ be a normalized eigenvector corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue $\mu_0$. We shall prove that $\boldsymbol{v}$ satisfies either $v_i>0$ for all $i$ or $v_i<0$ for all $i$. Define a vector $\boldsymbol{u}$ by $u_i=\left|v_i\right|$ for $i=1, \ldots, N$. Because $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a normalized eigenvector, we have
$$
\mu_0=\boldsymbol{v}^{\mathrm{t}} \mathrm{M} \boldsymbol{v}=\sum_{i, j=1}^N v_i m_{i, j} v_j \geq \sum_{i, j=1}^N u_i m_{i, j} u_j=\boldsymbol{u}^{\mathrm{t}} \mathrm{M} \boldsymbol{u},
$$
where we used (i). Since $\boldsymbol{u}$ is normalized and $\mu_0$ is the lowest eigenvalue, the variational principle implies that $\boldsymbol{u}$ is also an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\mu_0$. Then (1) implies $u_i>0$ (and hence $v_i \neq 0$) for all $i$. Since $\boldsymbol{u}^{\mathrm{t}} \mathbf{M} \boldsymbol{u}=\mu_0$, we have $\sum_{i, j} v_i m_{i, j} v_j=\sum_{i, j} u_i m_{i, j} u_j$. Since $\left(v_i\right)^2=\left(u_i\right)^2$, this means $\sum_{i \neq j} v_i m_{i, j} v_j=$ $\sum_{i \neq j} u_i m_{i, j} u_j$ (where the sum is over all $i$ and $j$ such that $i \neq j$ ). Since $u_i m_{i, j} u_j \leq 0$ for any $i \neq j$, we conclude that $v_i m_{i, j} v_j=u_i m_{i, j} u_j$ for any $i \neq j$. This means that $v_i v_j=u_i u_j>0$ whenever $m_{i, j} \neq 0$. From (ii), we see that all $v_i$ have the same sign.

We have $v_im_{i,j}v_j\ge -|v_im_{i,j}v_j|=u_im_{i,j}u_j$. Therefore, if $\sum_{i\ne j}v_im_{i,j}v_j=\sum_{i\ne j}u_im_{i,j}u_j$, we must have $v_im_{i,j}v_j=u_im_{i,j}u_j$ for all $i\ne j$.
